# ansible syntax for lineinfile search and replace

Tags: syntax, escaping, ansible

My current etc/group wheel is setup as the following
wheel:x:10:admin,sshgroup,domaingroup

I need it be
 wheel:x:10:admin4,sshlocal,domainusers,domainadmins

```
- name: add a string to the new file
  lineinfile:
    dest=/etc/group
    backrefs=true
    regexp='wheel:x:10:'
    line='wheel:x:10:admin4,sshlocal,domainusers,domainadmins'
    state = present
```

error:
The offending line appears to be:

```
    line='wheel:x:10:admin4,sshlocal,domainusers,domainadmins'
    state = present
```

^ here

I tried both with and without escaping : and commmas but to no avail. Can you please suggest. Im using ansible 2.2.1.0

Comment: You are mixing YAML and legacy syntax, you have a `\` character in a lot of places, none where you would actually need it, and you also have an extra `' "` at the very end

Comment: thanks for a quick reply. I updated my question with basic regexp - can you please help sort this out?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind guys, playbook ran this time. I think last line where state = present is listed, i looked like used tab spaces instead of spaces for yaml. After I deleted that line and readded it with spaces, it works now.

```
cat /etc/group | grep wheel
wheel:x:10:admin4,sshlocal,domainusers,domainadmins
```

Apparently, single quote is good enough to escape: characters in YAML - which is good.